# How to transpose or mirror xymatrix?

Tags: xy-pic

I know that it is possible to rotate `\xymatrix` (using e.g. `\xymatrix@d`) but how to transpose or mirror it?

Comment: Do you mean mirroring it keeping text not mirrored?

Comment: @karlkoeller: Yes, I mean logical mirroring like logical rotating with `\xymatrix@d` rather than "mechanical" mirroring.

Comment: I'm not aware of any option to do that.

Answer (score 2):

In `tikz-cd` you can mirror your diagrams by giving negative values to the row and column separators:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow{r}{\phi}& B\arrow{d}{\psi} \\
    C \arrow{u}{\eta} & D \arrow{l}{\mu}
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=-14ex, every arrow/.append style={swap}]
    A \arrow{r}{\phi}& B\arrow{d}{\psi} \\
    C \arrow{u}{\eta} & D \arrow{l}{\mu}
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=-11ex, every arrow/.append style={swap}]
    A \arrow{r}{\phi}& B\arrow{d}{\psi} \\
    C \arrow{u}{\eta} & D \arrow{l}{\mu}
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about one value positive and the other negative?

Comment: @egreg, I don't understand. Positive is the default. My first and second example are using the 'normal' value (5ex/6ex)

Comment: I was thinking to transposition

Comment: @egreg I somehow have to switch x and y coordinates here. Don't know yet. Did you have something concrete in mind by this "one positive, one negative"?

Comment: I tried and with both values negative one (quite obviously) gets a central symmetry. So no transposition, unfortunately. Forget about it.